# How to remove old location marker for new location in google map, Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps-markers

This code is work but i had a problem with marker, when i run my app it does shows marker but when i walk to change my location, the old location marker still appear on app and my latest location appear too, how can i remove the old location marker?

Here my Activity.java

```
package stmikbumigoramataram.intro;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private LocationListener locationListener;
Marker currLocationMarker;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }

    locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            double latitude = location.getLatitude();
            double longitude = location.getLongitude();

           if(currLocationMarker != null){
               currLocationMarker.remove();
           }

            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());
            try {
                List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                String str = addressList.get(0).getLocality()+", ";
                str += addressList.get(0).getCountryName();
                currLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(str));

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude)).zoom(15).build();
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }
    };


    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

}

protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
    Log.i("onPause...","paused");
}
}
```

[You can see result of my code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ot14K.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should firstly clear the Google map, then add a new marker that shows as previous marker remove and new marker add.

Use this line:

```
googleMap.clear();
```

and after add new marker on Google map.

Comment: ok thanks bro, honesly i find how to fix last night with this code if(currLocationMarker != null){
                    currLocationMarker.remove();
                }